# How to make async function based on promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

The problem is that the function does not wait until map will be finished

I think solution is Promise.all
But I do not know how to use this function

```
exports.createProduct = (data) => {
  var imgS3arr = []; //array which we waiting for
  data.img.map((img, i) => {
    fetch.remote(img).then((base) => {
        var buf = Buffer.from(base[0], 'base64');

        var imgS3 = {
            Key: data.title + i, //TODO: add random
            Body: buf,
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
        };

        s3Bucket.putObject(imgS3, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log('Error uploading data: ', data);
            } else {
                var params = this.request.params;
                var region = this.request.httpRequest.region;
                imgS3arr.push('https://s3-' + region + '.amazonaws.com/' + params.Bucket + '/' + params.Key)
            }
        }
      );
    }).catch((reason) => { });
});

//next part of code must be executed when all items pushed to 'imgS3arr'

const product = new Product({
    title: data.title,
    img: imgS3arr,  //we waiting for this array
});
return product.save((function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Added new! \n' + product);
    }
  }));
}
```

Can some one help me with this trouble?

Comment: You are mixing async with regular callbacks and promises.  The first thing to do is to convert all async operations in this block of code to promises.  Then, waiting with `Promise.all()` will be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// returns a promise that is resolved when everything is done
//    or rejected with the first error that occurs
exports.createProduct = (data) => {
    var imgS3arr = []; //array which we waiting for
    return Promise.all(data.img.map((img, i) => {
        return fetch.remote(img).then((base) => {
            var buf = Buffer.from(base[0], 'base64');

            var imgS3 = {
                Key: data.title + i, //TODO: add random
                Body: buf,
                ContentEncoding: 'base64',
                ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
            };

            return s3Bucket.putObject(imgS3).promise().then(function(data) {
                // given other changes here and unfamiliarity with this code
                // I'm unsure if `this` still has the right value in it here
                var params = this.request.params;
                var region = this.request.httpRequest.region;
                imgS3arr.push('https://s3-' + region + '.amazonaws.com/' + params.Bucket + '/' + params.Key)
            }).catch(function(err) {
                // log error, then rethrow to keep the promise rejected
                console.log(err);
                console.log('Error uploading data: ', data);
                throw err;
            });
        });
    })).then(function() {
            const product = new Product({
                title: data.title,
                img: imgS3arr, //we waiting for this array
            });
            // use database interface that uses promises, not plain callbacks
            return product.save(...);
        }
    });
}
```

Summary and explanation of changes made:

1. Inside of `data.img.map()`, return a promise so the `.map()` creates an array of promises.
2. Use `Promise.all()` on that array of promises to know when they are all done.
3. Switch to `s3Bucket.putObject(imgS3).promise()` so we can use promises instead of plain callback.
4. Rethrow error in `.catch()` after logging so promise stays rejected
5. Put code that you want to wait inside the `Promise.all().then()` handler.
6. Switch `product.save()` to the database interface that uses promises instead of plain callbacks so you can directly chain that promise (left for the OP to do since we don't even know what database it is).